# what does object.start() mean?

Tags: c#

Sorry i am new to C#. I have a program, where there is a class CatchFS. The main function in the class , has the code

CatchFS fs = new CatchFS(args);

fs.Start();

Can someone tell me what it means. I hv heard of thread.start() but object.start() is new to me . Am i even thinking right ?

Thanks a lot, Yes it is derived from a class called FileSysetm.cs. The start does this : public void Start () 
{ 
Console.WriteLine("start"); 
Create ();
 if (MultiThreaded) { 
mfh_fuse_loop_mt (fusep);
 }
 else { 
mfh_fuse_loop (fusep); 
}
 }

Now im trying to do a fusemount. The program starts and it hangs. there is some call that was not returned and i couldnt figure out which one. I tried using debug option of monodevelop, but no use, it runs only in my main function and I get thread started and thats it !!
I think the file FileSystem.cs is from library Mono.fuse.dll. Thanks for all your time. I hv been looking at this question for 2 whole days, and I dont seem to figureout much as to why the code wont proceed.Im expecting my azure cloud storage to be mounted in this fusemount point. My aim is after running this code I should be able to do an ls on the mountpoint to get list of contents of the cloud storage. I am also suspecting the mountpoint. Thanks a lot for providing me all your inputs.

Comment: I've voted to close for some reasons: First, we don't know what you libraries does, we can only speculate what the Start()-Method might do. Second, this is a very specialized question for a maybe not even public library.

Comment: I think closing this is a bit unfair.  It's just a beginner's misunderstanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no `object.Start` method. `Start` must be a method of the `CatchFS` class or some base class from which `CatchFS` derives.

If possible, consult the documentation for the library `CatchFS` comes from. That should hopefully explain what `CatchFS.Start` does.

If the documentation is sparse or nonexistent but you do have the source code, you can also simply take a look at the `CatchFS.Start` method yourself and try to figure out what its intended behavior is.

If there's no documentation and you have no source code, you're dealing with a black box. If you can contact the developer who wrote `CatchFS`, ask him/her what `Start` does.

One final option would be to download [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and use that to disassemble the compiled assembly from which `CatchFS` is loaded. Treat this as a last resort, as code revealed by Reflector is typically less readable than the original source.

Comment: Unless somebody created an Extension method for object maybe? Just a strange thought...

Comment: @Justin: Good point. Tough to imagine what that code could possibly do, though...

Comment: Using Reflector to look at the object is a possibility you might have missed.

Comment: There's always .NET Reflector

Comment: @Will Dean and @siride: Good call. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Start` is a method on the `CatchFS` class (or one of its parent classes) - you'll have to read the documentation or source for that class to find out what it actually means.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN Docs for Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.object_members(v=VS.80).aspx), there is no `Start` method. This must either be a method of `CatchFS` or one of it's base classes.